# Difference between methods of BoxClient and BoxManager?

Tags: c#, box

For uploading a file to Box, There are 2 ways

1. Create file by passing Byte[] with CreateFile method of BoxManager
2. Upload file by passing Filepath with UploadFile method of BoxClient.

Can anyone suggest which method is better and why?

I have to upload a file by URL. (I think I have to download first at the server and upload or create at Box.)

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be simpler to just pass in the FilePath

Comment: One seems to be for when you have a file on disk and the other when you want to avoid IO if the file data is already in memory.  So if you download the file in memory option one seems better.  If you download it to disk (because of size) then I'd go with option 2.